# Htaccess redirect all content from domain/folder to another domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website here:

[Wordpress Site](http://neo-mobili.com/wordpress/)

Now, i need to redirect all requests to that domain/directory to otherdomain, in this case [designcenter.com.ve](http://designcenter.com.ve) while keeping folder hierarchy as it is, for example:

```
http://olddomain/wordpress/post - to - http://newdomain/post or maybe http://newdomain/wordpress/post
```

Already tried some answers here, but no still luck, no redirecting and plus had to delete htaccess and restore permalinks on wordpress.

Somebody could shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need this rule **but make sure this rule is your first rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`** of `olddomain.com`:

```
RewriteRule ^wordpress(/|$) http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

In case your .htaccess is in `/wordpress/.htaccess` then use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

as your **first rule**.

Comment: Hi, you the htaccess guru hehehe, but this doesn't work man... :( -> http://neo-mobili.com/wordpress/ , and it's the only rule i have there, well gonna try on wordpress folder

Comment: If you already have `wordpress/.htaccess` then include 2nd suggested `RewriteRule` as the first rule just below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: Well, first rule on / (root) isn't working, the 2nd rule on wordpress folder seems to be working, but it gives me a loop redirect, it is maybe because on newdomin i have another htaccess pointing all traffic to newdomain to olderdomain??

Comment: Yes of course it will be an endless loop because this rule is sending all `wordpress/*` traffic to `newdomain` and `newdomain` is doing reverse.

Comment: Oh... Well i'll delete htaccess on newdomain and try

Comment: Another loop but with wordpress folder now, it's htaccess first rule on wordpress folder : http://www.designcenter.com.ve/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/wordpress/

Comment: Is `designcenter.com` your new-domain or old-doamin?

Comment: new-domain, neo-mobili.com/wordpress/* to -> designcenter.com.ve/*

Comment: Awesome, but how can i redirect with posts also? i mean newdomain/* (post, page, whatever) or this just works to redirect domain and that's it, i don't know if i'm explained myself, i wanted to keep wordpress hierarchy while redirecting just the domain, without actually visiting another server, that's same thing i made on olderdomain, you see, i can't install latest wordpress stuff on newdomain, so i need to keep this neo-mobili.com/wordpress site as it is, while redirecting domain neo-mobili.com to designcenter.com.ve, don't know if possible

Comment: Not sure how it will be possible, unless `neo-mobili.com and designcenter.com` are on same host and using same `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: No... they aren't :(, well gonna keep trying with this wordpress plugin and keep reading apache docs to see what can be done there, but thank you very very much for your interest, i'll write back as soon as i find a solution.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck. I will suggest you to create a new question with this different question and close this question since question was worded for the problem that we have resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^folder1(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, tried ´<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^wordpress(.*)$ http://designcenter.com.ve/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>´ But still nothing mate...

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer the popular [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin. Since you don't need to touch the .htaccess file. And you can manage everything from Wordpress Admin itself

**Update:2**: You can find all the basic redirect rules [here](http://www.steveroot.co.uk/2012/11/wordpress-redirects/).

Use this in regex... (Based on your usecase)

```
 Source: /(.*) 
 Target: http://newdomain.com/$1
```

**UPDATE**: I noticed... you haven't updated the permalinks in your 2nd site... Do that first and then also see the site URL is properly mentioned in your wordpress admin settings page.

Comment: I'm trying it, but no changes still... It just adds olderdomain/category/post/newdomain.com.ve

Comment: What Regex are you using ?

Comment: I'm not using regex, just adding sourceurl: /folder/category/post, targeturl: newdomain/folder/category/post, but now it just concatenate directions, it is a step forward maybe, is it mandatory to use regex?

Comment: Thank you so much, done like you said but nothing, check it out: http://neo-mobili.com/wordpress/, it should be http://newdomain/wordpress/ right?

Comment: Yes, seems like it's working, but says document not found on this server, sure it isn't but it should redirect to that domain keeping folder structure though

Comment: I mean, read the actual folder on olderdomain, while redirecting domain address only

Comment: Can you give me exact URLs from both the domains

Comment: Yes, sure, sorry i was sleeping, these are: http://neo-mobili.com/wordpress = olderdomain, http://designcenter.com.ve = new dmain

Comment: You mean General Settings? Says http://neo-mobili.com/wordpress Permalinks are updated, nothing yet

Comment: But wait a minute this will redirect to another hosting where the newdomain is pointed? meaning it will read not the actual installation path but another one?