# redirect from domain in same folder to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226696/htaccess-redirect-all-content-from-domain-folder-to-another-domain) is the similar question but it's not working. I need help.

going from olddomain.com/samefolder to newdomain.com/samefolder. They are both in the same structure/server (i.e. somepath/olddomain and somepath/newdomain). I cant write to the somepath root but I can write in roots of olddomain and newdomain.

I only want this to work for **one specific folder**.

Comment: What are you current rules? Show exactly what you have tried and what's not working.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?folder/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/folder/$1 [R,L]`
Im sorry for the delay

Comment: I got the above to work by putting it at the very very top of the file under `RewriteEngine On`. I'll close this